# RenderAs='PDF' Index in the Visual Force Component/Page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-index

I'm trying to create a Visualforce Component with the renderAs="PDF" and I'm stuck on the issue with the auto-number/index.
Is there a way to create the auto-number and a index page on the VF Page or Component?
On my testing it looks like javascript does not works on the PDF
I'm using a Component inside a VF Page with the tag, but, I'm informing both because if it is easy on VF Page or VF Component, I just change it.
Thanks in advance.

Edit

What I mean about auto-number/index is the following, like in the Contents of this image (found on internet), you may see (on the picture) that "Galleries" has the counter "1" refering to it's page and "Using Galleries" has the number "2", I would like to create this type of index on my PDF, getting the  on the html or something like this to create this kind of Index, but found no way to do it without the Java Script

[image]

Comment: Please edit your original post to include more detail on what the "auto-number/index" is, what objects are involved on the page, etc.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the feedback for my description, I've updated it, hope it is better to understand now.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to dynamically generate a table of contents. Your best bet is to use `page-break-after: always` to style the content you're iterating over to guarantee each item starts on its own page. Then on the first page, iterate over your data set and generate page numbers based off the index of the items. However, if your content is so long that it would overflow your page size, this approach will not work.

Comment: Too much bugs on this kind of solution, even with the 942.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to include page numbers inside of your PDF you can supply these dynamically with CSS in a `@page` rule. For example:

```css
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 2cm;
    @top-center { /* Page header, centered */
        content: "Header Text"
    }
    @bottom-right { /* Page footer, to the right */
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

You can also specify different rules for the first page of your document.

```css
@page :first {
    @top-right: { /* "content:normal" hides the page header */
        content: normal;
    }
}
```

Helpful references:

- https://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/CSS-Page-Tutorial-en.pdf
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: Hi, thank nbrown, but was not exactly that, I updated my description to make it to make it a little more clear.